# Button next to the users in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, button

I got a form with 7 users on it among each other. But I want to set 7 button next to it in a loop. Right now I've got this.

```
        int x = 12;
        int y = 30;

        foreach (details dets1 in detailsList)
        {
            var label = new Label();
            label.AutoSize = true;
            label.Location = new Point(x, y);
            label.Name = dets1.fname;
            label.Text = dets1.fname;

            this.Controls.Add(label);

            y += label.Height + 5;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
        {

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(200, 30);
            button.Text = "Off";
            button.Tag = i;
            button.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add(button);

            button.Click += button_Click;
        }
```

Comment: `button.Location = new Point(200, 30 + i * height);` where `height` is the height of each control associated with the user

Comment: still shows one button

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `Location`: you put *all* the buttons on the *same* place

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    ...
    button.Location = new Point(200, 30);
    ...
  }
```

Let's organaize all the buttons *vertically*:

```
  const int shift = 50;

  for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    ...
    button.Location = new Point(200, 30 + shift * i);
    ...
  }
```

Or *horizontally*:

```
  const int shift = 90;

  for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    ...
    button.Location = new Point(200 + shift * i, 30);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: It is both horizontal.

Comment: @discable10: no, please, notice, that I add to *y component* when I organize them vertically, and to *x-component* when horizontally.